# Navigation odometry and velocities published

Tags: navigation, odometry, velocity

**So why do I have to calculate the *VX* and *VTH* for odometry when move base from navigation stack actually publishes the velocities for my robot ... i don't get that can someone plz explain**.

```
current_time = ros::Time::now();
double DistancePerCount = (3.14159265 * 0.13) / 2626;
double lengthBetweenTwoWheels = 0.25;

// extract the wheel velocities from the tick signals count
deltaLeft = tick_x - _PreviousLeftEncoderCounts;
deltaRight = tick_y - _PreviousRightEncoderCounts;

omega_left = (deltaLeft * DistancePerCount) / (current_time - last_time).toSec();
omega_right = (deltaRight * DistancePerCount) / (current_time - last_time).toSec();

v_left = omega_left * 0.065; //radius
v_right = omega_right * 0.065;

vx = ((v_right + v_left) / 2)*10;
vy = 0;
vth = ((v_right - v_left)/lengthBetweenTwoWheels)*10;

double dt = (current_time - last_time).toSec();
double delta_x = (vx * cos(th)) * dt;
double delta_y = (vx * sin(th)) * dt;
double delta_th = vth * dt;

x += delta_x;
y += delta_y;
th += delta_th;

geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";

odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x;
odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y;
odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

// send the transform
odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

// Odometry message
nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
odom.header.stamp = current_time;
odom.header.frame_id = "odom";

// set the position
odom.pose.pose.position.x = x;
odom.pose.pose.position.y = y;
odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;

// set the velocity
odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";
odom.twist.twist.linear.x = vx;
odom.twist.twist.linear.y = vy;
odom.twist.twist.angular.z = vth;

// publish the message
odom_pub.publish(odom);
_PreviousLeftEncoderCounts = tick_x;
_PreviousRightEncoderCounts = tick_y;

last_time = current_time;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nav Stack publishes where the robot is asked to go, not what it is actually doing or where it actually is. That is what the odometry provides, ground truth of what the robot is actually doing.